# Android, Can't get a position that's not a place in google maps using PlacePicker

Tags: android, google-maps, gmsplacepicker

after choosing random postion that's not a place in Google Maps using PlacePicker (https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/placepicker),
i used `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:9.4.0'` the confirmation button is always disabled if the position not a registred place in Google Maps.[image]

Comment: +1 because google doesn't say to us that this is the problem. In much other cases there is nothing that works, instead of the half thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure you follow the complete setup guide for the Google Places API for Android: https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/start#app-config

Of particular note, your issue can happen if you don't have an API key in your app manifest. You'll need to follow the steps to set up an Android API key for Google Places from the Google Developer Console, and then add it to you application manifest:

```
<application>
...
    <meta-data>
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="YOUR_API_KEY"/>
</application>
```

You'll need to get an API key following the information in the Getting Started guide from Google.

Comment: I already add it, I made a map Actiivty and I create a custom UI picker.

Comment: Are you sure it's an Android API key, and you've specified your app package / SHA-1 fingerprint correctly when creating it?

I was able to perfectly reproduce this problem by removing the api key from a project, so that's definitely my best bet.

Comment: I aggree with Sampson, it was exactly the mistake I made. I hadn´t used the API Key correctly and it was only possible to pick up a place, not my own coordinates.

Comment: I miss configure the Android API key, I had a problem in the  SHA-1 fingerprint of my app. Thanks Sampson.